# Developing a static source code analysis tool for proprietary API?

Tags: c++, static-analysis

There is a proprietary API that is built on top of C++. So it uses all the features of C++ and then has its own APIs. There are some APIs that function exactly the same as C++ API (like for malloc there is Stralloc), these APIs are provided for performance reasons.

Though there are many static code analyzers available for C++, we cannot use any of them. There is a need to have a static code analyzer which could be run on the code with proprietary APIs.

I would like to know how do I begin developing the code analyzer. It may need not be very feature oriented like the ones available for C++. I want to start with basic stuff like reporting unused variables, buffer overflows, memory leaks.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

[UPDATE] I found the following question which is what I was looking for, only difference is, instead of Java my concern is for proprietary APIs. So far I have got couple of good answers but I would really like to know more from people who have been through such kind of development.

[Introduction to Static Analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411682/introduction-to-static-analysis)

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused:

Is this a language implementation on top of C++ or just a set of APIs on top of C++?

If the latter, any normal C++ profiler will capture things like memory leaks and overflows.

Comment: But surely such a profiler will be confused with things like boost::bind, signals, and other constructs which add non-imperative paradigms to C++.

Comment: Like I mentioned, there are APIs which are used in place of C++ APIs. For example instead of using free(), the Strfree() API is used which is exactly the same as free() but is used for performance reasons. So any normal C++ analyzer cannot recognize this.

Answer (score 2):

Solutions like Coverity and Klocwork have an extensible rule set where you can write your own rules.  You can also configure the tool so that their standard memory checks understand custom memory allocators.  Some limitations apply though.

It's useful to use these tools because then you can borrow off the same workflow.  Again, it depends on what you code you have and what exactly you are looking to do.

Comment: Yes, it’s better to use an existing tool than reinvent the wheel. Coverity’s documentation isn’t publicly available, but Klocwork’s is; see <http://docs.klocwork.com/documentation/Tuning_C/C%2B%2B_analysis_through_knowledge_bases#Using_the_conditional_ALLOC_record> for an example of creating a knowledge base entry for a function that behaves like malloc.  (Though if your source code ultimately calls malloc, you might not even need to do this; Klocwork might figure it out for itself.)

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to write this from scratch. C++ is notoriously difficult to even parse, and I don't think you'd get far on this route.

You should use an extendible C++ static analyser, so that you can write your own plugins to analyse your library calls. Off the top of my head, I would suggest:

- The gcc C++ front-end (gcc now has plugins)
- The EDG C++ parser
- [Rose](http://rosecompiler.org) (uses EDG)
- LLVM (perhaps using clang, but it might not be ready for primetime)
- Microsoft's Phoenix Framework (I assume it can do this, I have not checked).

The best answer is likely clang or rose.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing C++ is very hard in practice. If you have a C++ extended dialect, you need a full C++ parser that is "easily" bent to your dialect, and has means to build analysis tools.

The [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is fully customizable generic analysis and transformation infrastructure, providing general parsing, tree building, symbol table construction and flow analysis capabilities.  It is used to build fully custom analyzers.

It has a [C++ Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) that handles several standard dialects of C++, and can be customized to handle other extensions.  The C++ front end has full preprocessor capabilities, parses and builds ASTs, and does full C++ name and type analysis.